# Why do I have an error when I try a multiple import of icons in mui icons?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, material-ui, node-modules

I saw on the forum that there is a way to do a multiple import of Material UI icons, so I tried to go from this :

```
import InterestsRoundedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/InterestsRounded";
import AccountCircleRoundedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AccountCircleRounded";
import SettingsRoundedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/SettingsRounded";
```

to this

```
import { InterestsRoundedIcon, AccountCircleRoundedIcon, SettingsRoundedIcon } from "@mui/icons-material";
```

but when I try to launch my start my code I got this issue

> Compiled with problems:
> ERROR in ./src/components/sidebar/Sidebar.jsx 44:42-62
> export 'InterestsRoundedIcon' (imported as 'InterestsRoundedIcon') was not found in >'@mui/icons-material'

and I got those problems if i try to import either from "@mui/icons-material" or "@material-ui/icons"

Comment: You see in the code you share that you have to specify `sub folder` as well for the icons. They can not be destructured from the parent folder as they are not present there

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import {
  InterestsRounded as InterestsRoundedIcon,
  AccountCircleRounded as AccountCircleRoundedIcon,
  SettingsRounded as SettingsRoundedIcon,
} from "@mui/icons-material";
```